# Connecting DataGrip to Google Bigquery using GoogleCloud CLI

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

I read some of the documentation on how to access Bigquery on DataGrip as a data source. It is involving creating service accounts on GCP. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connect-to-bigquery.html) and [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/).

I know that we can access Bigquery projects using GCloud CLI, is there some way to leverage the GCloud CLI as a key to access Bigquery on DatGrip? So, we don't need to create a service account to grant the DataGrip to access the Bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bq` and `gcloud` also use some account authentication behind the scenes to access BigQuery, so no. You have to authenticate using some of the options available on the documentation you have linked (service account or user account).